# Marginal Likelihood and Its Intractability

Tags: likelihood

In case of VAE, it is said that the posterior distribution is intractable because the marginal likelihood is intractable.

[image]

My understanding as to why marginal likelihood is intractable:

z can have infinitely many possible values, which means the integration will have infinite standard operations. Hence, it will not be a closed form solution and thus is intractable.

Is my understanding correct? If not, could anyone please correct me on this?

**Another question**: can latent variable z be discrete? Since integration is only applied for continuous variables, if z is discrete, I think p(x) will be as follows:

p(x) = ∑ (|)()

Here, z will have fixed number of discrete values and p(x) will hence be tractable. With this, I am basically trying to understand whether or not the latent variables can be discrete in nature and marginal likelihood be tractable due to it in case of Variational Inference.

**One more confusion that I had is:** since z is latent (hidden), how can the values of z be known to be used in integration / summation?

Comment: What do you mean by infinitely many possible values? Integrals computed are over continuous sets. This does not mean the integral cannot be computed in all cases.

Comment: Are integrals computable even when we want to consider ALL values of continuous variable? Won't it be incomputable because there will be infinitely many possible values of continuous variable? Example: 1.3, 1.32, 1.322, 1.3221, 1.3222, 1.32444 and the list continues. @Xi'an

Comment: Also, besides intractability, the post consists of two other questions. Could you please provide me insight on those too? Or open the questions? @Xi'an

Comment: @Curious integrals only work for continuous variables. For discrete variables, you need to pretend that they are continuing to be able to use them. I recommend you start by checking the linked thread and refreshing your knowledge of calculus, at it might be needed to understand it better https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus

Comment: It seems like you are completely missing the concept of an integral. For instance,$$\int_0^1 e^{-z}\,\text dz=1-e^{-1}$$is tractable.

Comment: When $z$ only takes a countable number of values, the integral is understood in terms of $\text dz$ being the counting measure, which means that$$\int p(x|z)p(z)\,\text dz=\sum_z p(x|z)p(z)$$

Comment: @Xi'an with your latest comments, I now understand what you were implying in your first comment. Thanks! But, I have edited the post description to make my question more clear. Could you please take a look now and help me clear my doubts.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the link. Yup, I understand that integrals work with continuous variables. I think I was not able to convey my question clearly. I have edited my post to make my question clearer. Could you please take a look now and if possible, help me clear my doubts?